# Convert a dict into a list of dicts python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I would like to convert the following dictionary:

```
{'Stockholm': ['235', '35'], 'Helsinki': ['285', '15'], 
'Copenhagen': ['180', '60'], 'Berlin': ['185', '85'], 
'Prague': ['190', '115'], 'Warsaw': ['260', '105'], 
'Moscow': ['370', '80'], 'Sofia': ['275', '170'], 
'Ankara': ['340', '190'], 'Athens': ['285', '205']}
```

into:

```
[{'Stockholm':['235', '35']},{'Helsinki': ['285', '15']},
{'Copenhagen':   ['180', '60']},...,{'Athens': ['285', '205']}]
```

I'm out of ideas how to convert it.

Comment: `[{k: v} for k, v in dict.items()]`.

Comment: Dictionaries have no order. Is the output order important?

Comment: `[dict([k]) for k in d.items()]`

Answer (score 6):

You can use a list comprehension over the `dict.items()` pairs:

```
[{k: v} for k, v in d.items()]  # where d is your dictionary
```

This creates a separate dictionary for each key-value pair.

You can't rely on any order in the input dictionary, so the output order will depend on the insertion and deletion history of the dictionary (unless you are using Python 3.6 or up).

Demo:

```
>>> d = {'Stockholm': ['235', '35'], 'Helsinki': ['285', '15'],
... 'Copenhagen': ['180', '60'], 'Berlin': ['185', '85'],
... 'Prague': ['190', '115'], 'Warsaw': ['260', '105'],
... 'Moscow': ['370', '80'], 'Sofia': ['275', '170'],
... 'Ankara': ['340', '190'], 'Athens': ['285', '205']}
>>> [{k: v} for k, v in d.items()]
[{'Stockholm': ['235', '35']}, {'Helsinki': ['285', '15']}, {'Copenhagen': ['180', '60']}, {'Berlin': ['185', '85']}, {'Prague': ['190', '115']}, {'Warsaw': ['260', '105']}, {'Moscow': ['370', '80']}, {'Sofia': ['275', '170']}, {'Ankara': ['340', '190']}, {'Athens': ['285', '205']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way:

```
d = {'Stockholm': ['235', '35'], 'Helsinki': ['285', '15'], 
'Copenhagen': ['180', '60'], 'Berlin': ['185', '85'], 
'Prague': ['190', '115'], 'Warsaw': ['260', '105'], 
'Moscow': ['370', '80'], 'Sofia': ['275', '170'], 
'Ankara': ['340', '190'], 'Athens': ['285', '205']}
d = [d]
```